# Hibernate find method sometimes returns proxy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Lately my project encountered a really odd issue with JPA `findOne(id)` returning a proxy object instead of a full object.

Here is the scenario. Consider the entities and their connections shown below.

```
    @Table(name = "HOUSE")
        @Entity
        @EqualsAndHashCode
        @Setter
        @ReadPermission(expression = "user has rights for template snapshots AND has filter")
        public class HouseEntity extends VersionedEntity {

       @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "house", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
            public List<RoomEntity> getRooms() {
                return rooms;
            }
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "template", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
            public List<TableEntity> getTables() {
                return tables;
            }
        }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ROOMS")
    public class Room {
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        public HouseEntity getHouse() {
            return house;
        }
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "room", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
        public List<TableEntity> getTables() {
            return tables;
        }
    }

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLES")
public class TableEntity{
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "HOUSE_ID")
    public HouseEntity getHouse() {
        return template;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROOM_ID")
    public RoomEntity geRoom() {
        return room;
    }
```

As you can see, `House` has `Tables` and `Rooms`, `Rooms` also has `Tables`, and each child entity has a connection to its parents.

1. Add a table to the `HouseEntity`
2. Remove the table from the `HouseEntity` immediately after.

For 1, the `houseRepository.findById` gets my `HouseEntity` wrapped in proxy, as if it is lazy loaded.

The weird part is that if I do:

1. Add a table to a `RoomEntity`, which is a child of `HouseEntity`.
2. Remove the table from `RoomEntity`.

Then `houseRepository.findById` returns the `HouseEntity` without the proxy.

My question here is, why would this happen? Why would the `findById` method return a proxyed entity in this case? I need to have access to the normal entity without the proxy directly, even if the proxy has the entity populated in the target.